# Connecting to mysql server from docker container

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, spring-data-jpa

I am a total noob when it come to docker. I am working in docker toolbox on windows 10 and I am trying to dockerize my Java Spring Boot application that connect to MySQL database on my local machine using spring-data-jpa but when trying to run my container I am getting `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)`

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:60) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:67) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTables(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:329) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:65) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939) [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) [spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) [spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) [spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) [spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at com.docker.springboot.SpringBootDockerApplication.main(SpringBootDockerApplication.java:17) ~[classes!/:1.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:47) ~[Spring-Boot-Docker.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:86) ~[Spring-Boot-Docker.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[Spring-Boot-Docker.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) ~[Spring-Boot-Docker.jar:1.0]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:152) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:955) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        ... 59 common frames omitted

2019-07-18 19:46:03.053  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
2019-07-18 19:46:03.053 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2019-07-18 19:46:03.057 TRACE 1 --- [           main] o.h.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope     : Handling #sessionFactoryClosed from [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@26abb146] for TypeConfiguration
2019-07-18 19:46:03.058 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] o.h.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope     : Un-scoping TypeConfiguration [org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope@4b8729ff] from SessionFactory [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@26abb146]
2019-07-18 19:46:03.061  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
2019-07-18 19:46:03.067  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-07-18 19:46:03.102  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-07-18 19:46:03.105 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:47) [Spring-Boot-Docker.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:86) [Spring-Boot-Docker.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [Spring-Boot-Docker.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [Spring-Boot-Docker.jar:1.0]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:69) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTables(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTablesInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
        ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:152) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:955) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
        ... 59 common frames omitted
```

Docker run command:

```
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 3306:3306 spring-boot-docker
```

Dockerfile :

```
FROM openjdk:8
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 3306
ADD target/Spring-Boot-Docker.jar Spring-Boot-Docker.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/Spring-Boot-Docker.jar"]
```

application.properties file :

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/microservices?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root

## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Docker version:

```
$ docker version
Client:
Version:       18.03.0-ce
API version:   1.37
Go version:    go1.9.4
Git commit:    0520e24302
Built: Fri Mar 23 08:31:36 2018
OS/Arch:       windows/amd64
Experimental:  false
Orchestrator:  swarm

Server: Docker Engine - Community
Engine:
Version:      18.09.6
API version:  1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
Go version:   go1.10.8
Git commit:   481bc77
Built:        Sat May  4 02:41:08 2019
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Experimental: false
```

MySQL version: `8.0.16 (MySQL Community server-GPL)`.

Comment: instead of running locally you can run in a container use a volume to persist data on your host machine and then you can just address the db by name using compose.

Comment: Can you  please provide me with more details how I can do it.

Comment: I have a question, your MySQL container is running as docker service?

Comment: @AlirezaTizfahmFard I have NOT created container for MYSQL server , I just created one container for my spring-boot project that need to connect to MYSQL server in my local machine (localhost).

Comment: if run just in local machine use jdbc:mysql://0.0.0.0:3306/microservices?useSSL=false instead of jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/microservices?useSSL=false

Comment: @AlirezaTizfahmFard still throwing same exception.

Answer (score 1):

`openjdk:8` docker image does not provide a MySQL database running on `localhost:3306`. There are few ways you can approach your problem:

1. Configure JDBC URL to point from docker container to a host machine if you are running MySQL on host. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/1602555) to understand how to do this.
2. Start a new container running [`mysql:latest` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) and use `docker-compose` to start both.
3. Add MySQL to your docker image (not recommended, option 2 is preferred).

As you are starting go with option 1 and try to understand difference between container and host.

If you are doing this to learn docker I'd suggest to do all 3 options one by one and understand what are the differences. It would be a worthwhile exercise.

Comment: first I would like to Thank you for your reply @Karol. 
- if I change the `openjdk:8` image to different image so I can connect to MySQL server form inside the container? 
I doing this example just for learning, I tried Option #2 and its working with me, now I want to connect to external database.
I add `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` to `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini` and executing the following run command `docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 3306:3306 --network="host" spring-boot-docker`   but still no luck.
if there is any wrong about what I did and understand please advise me.